# Unkown column in 'field list' after creating tables by liquibase

Tags: spring, database, entity-framework, entity, liquibase

I prepare liquibase scripts to generate my tables and relationships.
ChangeLog which create relationships:

```
<changeSet id="1" author="xyz">
    <createTable tableName="drivers_and_tickets">
        <column name="driver_id" type="varchar(36)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="ticket_id" type="varchar(36)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_drivers"
                             baseTableName="drivers_and_tickets" baseColumnNames="driver_id"
                             referencedTableName="drivers" referencedColumnNames="id" />
    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_tickets"
                             baseTableName="drivers_and_tickets" baseColumnNames="ticket_id"
                             referencedTableName="tickets" referencedColumnNames="id" />
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="2" author="xyz">
    <createTable tableName="tickets_and_offences">
        <column name="ticket_id" type="varchar(36)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="offence_id" type="varchar(36)">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_tickets_from_offences"
                             baseTableName="tickets_and_offences" baseColumnNames="ticket_id"
                             referencedTableName="tickets" referencedColumnNames="id" />
    <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_offences"
                             baseTableName="tickets_and_offences" baseColumnNames="offence_id"
                             referencedTableName="offences" referencedColumnNames="id" />
</changeSet>
```

And it ok, app is starting without any errors.
I use hibernate too, so I prepared entites:

```
public class DriverEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="driver")
    private List<TicketEntity> tickets;

public class TicketEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    private LocalDate date;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="ticket")
    private Set<OffenceEntity> offences;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id")
    private DriverEntity driver;
```

and next when I call repository findAllDrivers I am getting error:
"Unknown column 'tickets0_.driver_id' in 'field list'" .

When I was using hibernate.ddl-auto mapping like that in entities was enough to create tables and getting records from database.

Edit:
I have checked how it looks in my DB and do not know what is wrong
[image: look_in_intellij]

Comment: have you tried using @Column(name="") for your fields to reference the database rows?

Comment: When I add @Column(name="id") up on id filed in entity I am stuill getting "Unknown column 'tickets0_.driver_id' in 'field list'"

Comment: Yes but is your row in db called "id" or "driver_id"?